# Discourse Install failed $LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL

Tags: docker, discourse

I dont know how to fix it.. and install properly discourse

**FAILED**

> Pups::ExecError: /bin/bash -c "if [[ ! \"$LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL\" =~ ([^@]+)@([^.]+) ]]; then echo \"LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL is not a valid email address\"; exit 1; fi" failed with return #
>   Location of failure: /pups/lib/pups/exec_command.rb:108:in `spawn'
>   exec failed with the params {"cmd"=>["if [ -z \"$LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL\" ]; then echo \"LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL ENV variable is required and has not been set.\"; exit 1; fi", "/bin/bash -c \"if [[ ! \\"$LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL\\" =~ ([^@]+)@([^\.]+) ]]; then echo \\"LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL is not a valid email address\\"; exit 1; fi\""]}
>   76a7274dbc42c5beca2c6ed2e47d4862183a64938a2fcbe789598fd37809fcfe
>   ** FAILED TO BOOTSTRAP ** please scroll up and look for earlier error messages, there may be more than one

I am trying to install it on my computer -> localhost , debian9

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile. Seems like your missing to set an environment variable

Comment: how can to do it?

Comment: How do you want to deploy discourse? You added a "docker" tag, so I thought you are using docker. Please extend your Question with more details about the installation process and your configuration. Otherwise this is unsolvable.